# Synchronization two SQL Server databases without link beetween

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, compact-database

I have central SQL Server 2008 Enterprise database and many clients with SQL Server 2008 Express databases. And I have a task for synchronization between central database and client's databases: download sales data from clients and load into server and download reference information from server to every client database. 
Online synchronization I was make with SyncFramework via Web-service. Now I want develop offline synchronization when link with Web-service is broken or miss. 
I think use also SyncFramework with next schema:

1. Download data from client (SQL Server Express) to SQL Server Compact database
2. Move SQL Server Compact database file to server
3. Upload data from compact database to SQL Server Enterprise

But I don't found examples or articles about this solution. 
What are you think - this method is work? May be exist more simple and elegant variant?

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework supports peer to peer synchronization. if you use SqlSyncProvider, you can provision a Sql Compact database (using SqlCeSyncProvider) to sync with your Sql Express(using SqlSyncProvider). you can then upload this Sql Compact database and synchronize it with your server (using SqlSyncProvider). see [Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617382%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

the steps would be:

1. provision your Sql Server for sync
2. provision Sql Express for sync
3. Provisioin Sql Compact for sync
4. Sync Sql Express with Sql Compact
5. Upload Sql Compact to server
6. Sync Sql Compact to Sql Server